# Can you find who is dead

Tags: situation

Look at the picture and find who is dead?

[image]

Source:
[BRIDDLES.COM](https://briddles.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it

> The girl in the red shirt?

Because

> She’s eating a sandwich that looks like it’s 2 years old, and that might kill her?

Comment: And there could be some dead meat in the sandwich. LOL.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, lol